# Urls for REST methods

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm trying to get my head around the correct way to represent the following methods in a restful manner...

Say I have x amount of servers and they run Windows, Linux and Unix.

Each server can have a ping, shutdown and user action ran against them.

The API has no knowledge of the server so a request would have to provide the IP address along with server type, and action type (which it does know about).

With that in mind, these simple URLs come to mind but aren't restful in the slightest:

```
/192.168.1.3/Linux/ping 
/192.168.1.5/windows/shutdown
```

Should I go down the restful route? Or is the above ok for a simple web API?

If restful would it look this?

```
GET /servertypes/{servertypeId}/actions/{actionId}?serverip=192.168.1.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to make more sense to me:

`GET /servertypes/{servertypeId}/{serverip}/{action}`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should rethink your design.

You're effectively overriding the semantics of HTTP methods by placing the command names in the URLs, which are meant to represent scoping information. `GET` requests [should not lead to changes of state](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1). Ignoring the underlying protocol is not considered RESTful.

What you have here looks like an RPC model that doesn't really fit the principles of REST. It seems to me that you're trying to hammer a square peg into a round hole.

You should also ask yourself if it's really necessary to expose the underlying OS. Do you want to call system-specific commands? Should it be possible to run any executable or just a couple of common ones? Should you care if it's `grep` on a UNIX machine or `findstr` on a Windows box? Does the client care if they use a Windows or a Linux machine?

You could go for a simple pattern similar to what Uzar Sajid suggested. It would probably work alright. Just don't call it RESTful cause it's not.

Comment: Oops I hit "add comment" to quick .

Comment: Cheers for the reply Tom.    The point about the OS is it needed so the right command is run as the api has no knowledge of the server type just from the ip so the question how should the request present the info Everything I've read about restful Apis suggest Uzair's URL is incorrect which is why I'm asking the question.  I don't think rest is the answer but wanted to but the question to you experts.

Comment: Thinking RPC might be best seems to fit better "An RPC is initiated by the client, which sends a request message to a known remote server to execute a specified procedure with supplied parameters."

Comment: @Adam I can't help but wonder why you're trying to come up with a solution like this. Wouldn't it be easier and more secure to establish an SSH/remote desktop connection when you want to execute something on a specific machine?

Comment: The idea is to abstract the heavy loading from web devs and let the api take care of it. Writing a HTML/javascript app to run commands should then be simple.